# how can i stream a video from my c# app using libvlc?

Tags: .net, video, streaming, libvlc

I am trying to write a client-server videostreaming app in c# and i am using libvlc.
The client is working fine, but i am not sure how can i do the server.
It is like the client, with the modification to media AddOptions method? and then play the media?

UPDATE: I have tried this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MyLibVlc vlc = new MyLibVlc();
        string[] args = new string[] { "-I", "dummy", "--ignore-config","" };
        instance = new VlcInstance(args);
        //:sout=#rtp{dst=79.114.124.180,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=1} :sout-keep
        player = null;
        string source = "D:\\CM.mp4" ;
        VlcMedia media = new VlcMedia(instance, source);
        string[] options=new string[]{":sout=#rtp{dst=79.114.124.180,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=1} :sout-keep"};
        media.AddOptions(options);
        if (player == null)
        {
            player = new VlcMediaPlayer(media);
        }
        else
        {
            player.Media = media;
        }
        player.Play();

    }
```

and i have looked in the log file. Could not open file...
I passed the arg in a wrong way, or something is missing.

Answer (score 3):

I knew it is a very long time ago question, but it still has more than 1k views, so maybe someone will need it like me after looking and testing around hours.

> "It is like the client, with the modification to media AddOptions method? and then play the media?"

Yes. You just need to modify the media AddOptions.

> "and i have looked in the log file. Could not open file... I passed
>   the arg in a wrong way, or something is missing."

This is an example option that I successfully tested.
Note that maybe some options could be abundant for your case.

```
media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://192.168.1.123:554/stream.sdp}");

media.AddOption(":sout-keep");
```

In creating media, I also need to give the exactly FromType param.

```
var media = new Media(libVlc, "C:\\foo.avi", FromType.FromPath);
```

If you want to stream from other sources such as another RTSP source so it will be:

```
var media = new Media(libVlc, "rtsp://192.168.1.234:555/live/0/MAIN", FromType.FromLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example demonstrating how to stream a video with LibVLCSharp:

```
using System;
using LibVLCSharp.Shared;

namespace VlcStreaming
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serverIpAddress = "192.168.1.101";
            var streamUrl = $"rtsp://{serverIpAddress}:554/stream.sdp";

            LibVLCSharp.Shared.Core.Initialize();

            var libVlc = new LibVLC();
            var media = new Media(libVlc, "fe48f269-4f89-4c58-afd4-04c2e2e3f10f.MP4");

            media.AddOption(
                $":sout=#transcode{{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}}:rtp{{mux=ts,sdp={streamUrl}}}");
            media.AddOption(":sout-keep");

            var player = new MediaPlayer(media);

            player.Play();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to install the **LibVLCSharp** library, as well as the LibVlc library for your platform (**VideoLAN.LibVlc.Windows** in my case).

You can then connect to the stream URL from VLC player (you will need to open port 554 if connecting from another machine etc).

Answer (score 0):

Regards AddOption / Options.. Take a not that you must separate each option, and not use the Vlc-Media-Mplayer given format (can be confusing!), the error received won't help you figure it out!

so, if Vlc-ML options are,

e.g.

```
":sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=12345,mux=ts} :no-sout-all :sout-keep"
```

they must be separated to this:

```
            media = new Media(m_libVlc, p_fileInfo.FullName, FromType.FromPath, 
                @":sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=12345,mux=ts}",
                @":no-sout-all", 
                @":sout-keep");
```

Hope this helps other (took me quite some time to figure, with the help of #cube45 :)